# missing text value in ionic-select using ionic 3

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am having some issues with ion-select. The text value is not shown in ion-option. Please see the following figure for reference:

[image]

I added ion-select by using the following code. It is quite straight forward and doesn't even use a model. I still don't understand that is it because of the ionic version (or) may be angularJS? Can anyone enlighten me on how to solve this issue?

```
 <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Gender</ion-label>
    <ion-select>
      <ion-option value="f">Female</ion-option>
      <ion-option value="m">Male</ion-option>
    </ion-select>
  </ion-item>
```

Here is my package.json:

```
{
"name": "ionic-hello-world",
"version": "0.0.0",
"author": "Ionic Framework",
"homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
"private": true,
"scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
},
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/core": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/forms": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/http": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.1.3",
    "@ionic-native/app-availability": "^4.1.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "3.10.2",
    "@ionic-native/diagnostic": "^4.1.0",
    "@ionic-native/file": "^3.12.1",
    "@ionic-native/geolocation": "^3.14.0",
    "@ionic-native/http": "^3.12.1",
    "@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "^3.12.1",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "3.10.2",
    "@ionic-native/sqlite": "^3.12.1",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "3.10.2",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.0.1",
    "cordova-android": "^6.2.3",
    "cordova-plugin-appavailability": "^0.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-console": "1.0.5",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "1.1.4",
    "cordova-plugin-geolocation": "^2.4.3",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "~4.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "2.2.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "1.3.1",
    "cordova.plugins.diagnostic": "^3.6.6",
    "ionic-angular": "3.3.0",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "~2.2.1",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.4.0",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.12"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "1.3.7",
    "@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova": "1.6.2",
    "@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular": "1.4.1",
    "ionic": "3.7.0",
    "typescript": "2.3.3"
},
"cordovaPlugins": [
    "cordova-plugin-console",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
    "cordova-plugin-device",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard"
],
"cordovaPlatforms": [],
"description": "HaT: An Ionic project",
"cordova": {
    "plugins": {
        "cordova-plugin-console": {},
        "cordova-plugin-device": {},
        "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
        "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
        "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
        "ionic-plugin-keyboard": {},
        "cordova-plugin-appavailability": {},
        "cordova-plugin-geolocation": {},
        "cordova.plugins.diagnostic": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
        "android"
    ]
}}
```

Comment: try to add the font color to black under your scss and try it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ion-list radio-group>
  <ion-list-header>
    Gender
  </ion-list-header>

  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Male</ion-label>
    <ion-radio value="a"></ion-radio>
  </ion-item>

  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Female</ion-label>
    <ion-radio value="b"></ion-radio>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Try using this code

Comment: Actually I want to use popup ion-select instead of ion-item. is there any issue on it? framework problem?